# Why are the multiline UILabels in my UITableViewCell truncating on first load, but correcting themselves on scroll?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I’m having an issue with one of my tableviews in my app, and wonder if anyone has come across something similar. I have 2 labels in a custom tableviewcell – a `questionLabel` and an `answerLabel` – which have the following constraints:

[image][image]

On both UILabels I have the number of lines set to 0, to make them multi-line, and have added the `preferredmaxLayoutWidth`property to both too as follows:

```
cell.questionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.questionLabel.frame.width
cell.answerLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.answerLabel.frame.width
```

I also have the following in the `viewDidLoad()` method, as per other StackOverflow suggestions:

```
self.faqTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.faqTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140.00
```

On first load, the labels are still becoming truncated, even though lines are set to 0, and weirdly at inconsistent places of the label. However, when scrolling the screen down and then back up to the top, the labels auto-correct themselves and the layout is perfect. See screenshot below:

[image]

Has anyone come across this issue before, and if so could you point me in the right direction. I'm not sure whether it's something I've failed to set, or a problem with my auto layout constraints.

Comment: Have you set `lineBreakMode`?

Comment: Aaargh, I was in the spot as you are now, and I still cannot find an exact solution after several years of iOS development. This is one of the reasons I hate Auto Layout with a passion.

Comment: @Priya haven't set anything for this, but it's set to 'truncate tail', which I assume is the default. Changing these just truncates the text differently, but the problem is still there.

Comment: set label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

Comment: @Priya The issue still remains, but without the ellipses `...`'s

Comment: set your line break mode, I dont think you need to set the top spacing AND the bottom spacing between the two labels. just one will suffice to calculate the layout height and spacing. You could try adding a greaterThanOrEqual to constraint to both for the height, or just embed them both in a vertical stack view.

Comment: Pl check Content Hugging and Compression Resistance Priority of both labels

Comment: @Scriptable Tried embedding in a stack view and adding greaterThanOrEqual, but to no avail. Setting the top and bottom spacing differently, as you mention, also doesn't alter the behaviour :(

Comment: @Priya I've played around with 'Content Hugging and Compression Resistance Priority' for the labels, and this doesn't seem to do much either, I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Add constraints like this. Delete the below lines

```
cell.questionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.questionLabel.frame.width
cell.answerLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.answerLabel.frame.width
self.faqTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140.00
```

Set the UILabel's number of lines to zero and implement the below method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying this out. Unfortunately, although it solves the truncating issue, it introduces issues that I was having previously, where the spaces between question and answer labels are inconsistent across different cells, plus the separators were being hidden or covered over for some reason. This was solved by these lines, but obviously they bring about the new problem that this question is trying to solve:
```
cell.questionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.questionLabel.frame.width
cell.answerLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.answerLabel.frame.width
```

Comment: Actually, it's just in the simulator that the separator lines are missing! On an actual device, the lines are visible. The only small issue i'm having is that on the first cell, the space between the question and answer labels is a little too big, but as far as I'm concerned, that's a big improvement. I think this sorts out the main issues I was having.

Comment: Did this actually solve the truncating issue for you? I'm in the exact same dilemma, and I've implemented all of the constraints and heightForRowAt protocol, and still get truncated cells on first display (until scroll up/down)